# how to use mocks properly

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have foolowing class which I would like to mock:

**BusineesLayer:**

```
/**
 * Created by Alexandr on 14.05.2016.
 */
public class BusineesLayer {
    public  OrderModel orderModel;
    public DbService dbService;
    ...

    public BusineesLayer(OrderModel orderModel,DbService dbService) {
        this.orderModel = orderModel;
        dbService = dbService;
    }
    public BusineesLayer() {

    }

    public boolean checkItemsInDb(List<Items> items) throws HandleOrderExeption {
       ...
      return result

    }



    public boolean handleOrder() throws HandleOrderExeption {

        checkItemsInDb(orderModel.getItemsList());

        boolean res =dbService.addOrder(orderModel.getItemsList(),
                            orderModel.getCustumerName(),
                            countTotalSum(orderModel.getItemsList())
                            );

        return res;
    }


}
```

I would like to test `hanldeOrder()` method and in order to make it less excess insted of checkItemsinDb() inside   invoke "true";

So, my test looks like this:

```
@Test
    public void handleorderTest() {
   ...
        BusineesLayer layer = Mockito.mock(BusineesLayer.class);

        layer.dbService = busineesLayer.dbService;
        layer.orderModel = busineesLayer.orderModel;

        Mockito.when(layer.checkItemsInDb()).thenReturn(true);

        boolean  res = layer.handleOrder();

        assertThat(res, equalTo(true));
    }
```

but it always return false and doesn't go through `handlOrder()` at all

Is any ways to solve it? Or how can I refactor my code to test it?

Comment: Mockito.when(layer.handleOrder()).thenReturn(true); ?

Comment: I want handleOrder to be worked out fully, but insted it's inner method checkItemsInDb() invoke just true

Comment: If you want to *test* the Business layer, then you want to *mock* the service layer. You don't mock what you're testing, you mock the stuff it uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not test mocks, you use mocks to help you test.

I think you've just become confused at how you are using mocks. Mocks allow us to simulate and can responses to objects we are testing. If you're testing the `handleOrder` method, then you should mock anything that interacts with that method, in this case `DbService` and `OrderModel`.

```
@Test
public void handleorderTest() {
    BusineesLayer layer = new BusineesLayer(); //we are testing this!
    DbService dbService = Mockito.mock(DbService.class);
    OrderModel orderModel = Mockito.mock(OrderModel.class);

    layer.dbService = dbService;
    layer.orderModel = orderModel;

    Mockito.when(orderModel.getItemsList()).thenReturn(new ArrayList<Items>());
    Mockito.when(dbService.foo()).thenReturn(true);

    //mock up multiple calls so your service will provide true

    boolean  res = layer.handleOrder();

    assertThat(res, equalTo(true));

    //repeat for false, and so on
}
```

---

If, however, you are trying to test the `dbService` call, then you should create a test for it without the business layer at all. The business layer doesn't depend on anything except calls to other methods, so whether you use those real objects or mocked versions of those objects, the functionality should be the same. The business logic only appears to fail if DBService or OrderModel break, so you would test service and model separately (without involving the business layer) to test those.